# Why is my German Shepherd scratching their mouth and ear?

Tags: dogs, diseases, ears-nose-throat

My German Shepherd is scratching the upper part of his mouth and the inside of his left ear recently. I want to know, what would be the reason for this?

Comment: It might help those that will answer this if you provide more details such as age, recent exposures to different environments, daily routine (walks and such).

Comment: S/he may have an ear infection - a visit to the vet is probably the best thing

Comment: yes. it seems like infection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments it does sound like an ear infection and would warrant a vet visit.

### Signs of an ear infection:

- Head shaking
- Head tilt
- Excessive scratching
- Hair loss or scabbing around the ears (from scratching)
- Foul odor
- Discharge from the ear

### Causes

- Allergies
- Frequent swimming without drying the ears
- Inadequate ear cleaning (especially in floppy eared dogs)
- [Polyps](http://www.ovrs.com/blog/ear-polyps-pets-pet-owners-need-hear/)
- Ear mites

### What to expect

During the exam the veterinarian will use an otoscope to look inside your dogs ear to check for:

1. Inflamation
2. Excess debris
3. Appearance of the ear drum

After the otoscopic exam a sample of the debris from both ears will be taken to view under a microscope. The most common types of infection are:

1. Bacterial
2. Fungal

Each type of infection needs a specific medication though most veterinary ear medications treat both types.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The Vet has mentioned that this was happened due to a small insect or something related to bacteria. The Dog was treated by the doctor with three injection and some tablets. it seems to be fine with the ear but not with the mouth scratching

Comment: @kevin So shes scracthing the inside of her mouth?

Comment: @Kevin Sounds like possibly Demodex? Your description doesn't sound like a simple ear infection, and we often find Demodex around the mouth.

Comment: @HarryV. ya my first thought was ears as when they scratch it can look like they're scratching both simultaneously

Comment: @HarryV  Yes. it's like demodex (i dont know the terms but i read something on it) .

Comment: The most recent demodex case i seen was noticed from patchy skin on its face, never even thought about the scratching.